# sql server like clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, like-keyword

Hey guys,  I have a column in an sql server table that is nvarchar(max).  I query the table with:

`select * from CrossArticle_Article where Summary like '%PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Tim%'`

If I enter 5 words in the like clause, I get a result, if I add more words, I dont get any results, even if the record exists.  Is there any limitation for the records?

Comment: No. Can you gives us an example of failing text? Also are you using parameters or variables? If so what is the definition (especially length) of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limitation. I suspect the `LIKE` clause is behaving properly, but your data is the cause of you not getting the results you're expecting.

Can you post some data to help illustrate those records that you expect in your resultset?

```
declare @foo table (title Nvarchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO @foo (title) 
values ('South PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Tim X'),
('North PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Timofei'),
('In West-PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Timothy Born and raised'),
('PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Timmy Smith'),
('<p>PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Tim Motzer finds infinite joy in diversity. His output as a leader and sideman crisscrosses multiple musical universes, including jazz, fusion, prog, hip-hop, soul, electronica, and the avantgarde.')

-- results in 5, as expected
select count(*) from @foo 
where title like '%PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Tim%' 

-- results in 1, as expected
select count(*) from @foo 
where title like '%PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Timmy S%'
```

Comment: @Campbell: 
This is my Query which i am using..
select * from CrossArticle_Article where Summary like '%PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND composer Tim%'

This is my summary field, where like clause is applied.

<p>PHILADELPHIA-BASED GUITARIST AND  composer Tim Motzer finds infinite joy  in diversity. His output as a leader and  sideman crisscrosses multiple musical  universes, including jazz, fusion, prog,  hip-hop, soul, electronica, and the avantgarde.

Comment: @campbell: data type of summary field is nvarchar(max).

Comment: @Abbas: try copy/pasting the above ad-hoc SQL into SQL Server. What does it result for you? How does my query differ from yours?

Comment: @campbell: The above ad-hoc query works fine until i dont remove the 4th row. if i do that, then i do not gets anything in the result set, i think <p> is creating issue, but also i have used '%%' in like clause, so this must not be an issue